# Web App with Rest Services

Tags: mysql, html, rest, netbeans-8

The task assigned to me is to create a web application that will have both Client (HTML5 App) & Server  in the same PC (mine). I have to perform CRUD. 
Based on the Online tutorials I can create HTML app & Server (using Rest services) in netbeans.

How will i send the data entered in the HTML page to server (how to use the rest services for CRUD). In which format I should send the data to server and how to get the data from the server.   I am using netbeans. Please say in Java and not in Php.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript/jQuery to call the WebServices.

And use JSON to formatting the data.

Here an small example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://your_domain/',
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'ID=1&Duration=10&ABC=XYZ',
    success: function() { alert('Request completed'); }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I have used angularJS and could do it.